# How do i use lodash with Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, lodash

I've just started working on a new project, using Ionic 2. I'm new to TypeScript, and have been trying to figure out how to include lodash to my project.

Is there anyone out there who has done this, and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install `lodash` with `npm` from your terminal:

   ```
   $:npm i -S lodash 
   // npm install --save lodash (--save,-S saves to package.json)
   ```
2. Import lodash in your component like this:

   ```
   import * as _ from 'lodash';
   ```

Comment: You can also get the [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash) with: `npm install --save @types/lodash`

Answer (score 14):

Starting from [Ionic 2 RC0](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#typings) you have to do the following.

```
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev --save-exact
```

and import it like

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 12):

**For Future Users of Ionic 3**

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save
```

[**Official Doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/)

`npm install` will download a copy of the library from NPM and save it in your app’s node_modules directory. `--save` will tell the NPM CLI to add an entry to your app’s package.json dependency list. 
You can use the library now.

If you want to import all functions from lodash then use

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
lodash.capitalize('myStringToCapitalize');
```

If you want to use specific function from lodash then use

```
import { shuffle } from 'lodash';
shuffle(results);
```

Comment: btw, if I use `import { range } from 'lodash';` - why using `range` directly in the template isn't recognized ? I need to create in my `ts` file something like: `range(min,max) { return range(min,max) }; `

Answer (score 10):

Actually none of the answers above mention that you need to install `lodash`'s type definitions if you are trying to use `lodash` in your ionic 2 app. To install `lodash`'s type definitions to your project run the following commands:

- Install `typings` node module as global (if you have not already): `sudo npm install typings --global`
- Install `lodash` to your project: `npm install lodash --save`
- Install `lodash`'s type definitions: `typings install lodash --save`

Once you are finished installing `lodash`'s type definitions to your project you can import `lodash` to your ionic2 .ts file like this:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

UPDATE: 10/02/2017 Ionic team published a document how to use 3rd party libraries in Ionic projects. Please refer here to see an example of how to use lodash with latest ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/

Comment: this suggestion worked partially for me. the last command did not work. the flag `--ambient` is now deprecated, and the console says to use `--global` however when you use `--global` it then complains and advises you to remove the `--global` option. basically, `typings install lodash --save` worked for me (after executing the previous two commands you suggested). thanks!

Comment: Worked for me when i installed typings lodash. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**For angular 2**

1. Install lodash with npm:

   npm i -S lodash
2. Import lodash like this:

   import * as _ from 'lodash';

**For angular 1.x**

1. Install packages with bower:

   bower install --save ng-lodash
2. Include scripts in your index.html between ionic.bundle.js and app.js:
3. Add module as a dependency to your app

   angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngLodash'])
4. Inject into your controller and start using it

   .controller('yourController', function($scope, lodash) {
     lodash.assign({ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }, { 'c': 3 });
   });

Comment: This will probably work for Ionic 1, but the question was for Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

For me its working with type definition on ionic 2 (2.0.0.beta.11)

steps

```
sudo npm install typings --g
```

Secondly

```
npm install lodash --save
```

and

```
typings install lodash --save
```

Finally use lodash into project with

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

and

```
var index = _.indexOf(albumList, data.album.id)
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This must be the Correct answer With Ionic 2.1.0**

Try this:

```
npm install -g typings
typings search lodash
typings install lodash --save
```

Maybe this [**blog**](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-typings/) may help you

Answer (score 1):

Since it's all depended on the Ionic 2 version you're using, and none of the above was 100% my solution, but did get me to the right point eventually.
I want to add my version of the answer for the following version of `Ionic 2`

```
ionic framework version: 3.5.0
typescript: 2.3.3
```

And I didn't had to install anything, `Lodash` was simply there inside the `node_modules/lodash` directory.

The only thing I did inside my application `.ts` files is:

```
import * as Lodash from 'lodash';

// Inside the class
new_array = Lodash.shuffle(data_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that for each component you can add the specific `lodash` type 
instead of importing all of lodash with what has been mentioned before `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

So in the component if you are only using `isMatch` you can just easily add it as

```
import { isMatch } from 'lodash';
```

and then use it like so

```
isMatch(this.foo1, this.foo2);
```

This explicitly declares what you are using and helps with maintainability when working with more then 1 dev on a component